# Can the instance of the class be stored in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Factory(FeatureClass) {
  return class extends React.Component { 
     constructor() {
        this.feature = new FeatureClass();
     }
    // ...
  }
}

// other component
const NewComponent = Factory(...)
this.setState({
  Components: [...this.state.Components, <NewComponent />]
});
```

Featureclass is an abstract class,Its subclasses are dynamically determined.

State must be plain object ?

Comment: No, do what you did in the `Factory` and store instances of classes/components as component properties rather than in the state. The state should be reserved for raw data.